# bitwise negate and bitwise XOR 1 not equivalent?

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, xor, negate

My discrete math tells me that negate every bit of a binary number is equivalent to XOR it with 1. That is:

```
~1010 === 0101
1010 XOR 111 = 0101
```

But this doesn't hold in javascript:

```
~123 === -124
123 ^ 1 === 122
```

Why?

Comment: 1 in decimal isn’t the same as 111 in binary.

Comment: The generalization to arbitrary widths is to XOR with -1 (which also works for the single-bit case)

Comment: @harold can you explain why that works?

Comment: @Boyang because "all bits set", at any length, is the -1 for that length. Proof: adding 1 to it carries through all the bits and results in zero. "all bits set" + 1 = 0, so "all bits set" = -1.

Comment: @harold Ok. You can add an answer if you will, and I will accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1 is not binary 111

Negating every bit of a number is equivalent to XOR *every bit* with 1, i.e., with a number of equal size where all bits are 1.

For a single byte, you'd want to xor with binary 11111111 which equals to decimal 255, not 1. Decimal 1 is binary 00000001, so in a bitwise XOR you're flipping only the last bit.

Comment: Ok. How can I make sure I'm XORing with 11111...? Maybe 123 ^ (2**32)?

Comment: 2**32 is 100...000. Usually you'd just write the hex constant 0xFFFFFFFF which is equal to 32 bit 11...11.